# using two build_opener at once

Tags: python

I'm a newbie with Python, and I'm trying to build a simple script to download a remote HTML file for parsing the content.

I need to use the both a proxy as well as a cookie enabled enviroment to authenticate with the remore system.

As long as I use just one handler, everything is fine. However, as soon as I try to use the combination of the Cookie handler and the proxy handler, at the first connection the python script raise an exception.

```
self.cj = CookieJar()
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":"http://193.104.35.23:80"})
self.opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support, urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cj))
urllib2.install_opener(self.opener)

self.opener.open('http://www.mysite.com').read()
```

and in the console I get the following messages.

pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/fnmatch.py
pydev debugger: Unable to find real location for: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py

There are some other errors like this as soon as the script starts the execution, but without using the proxy everything runs fine.

Also, after a while, the script ends with this

urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

Which is pretty self-explanatory, but I can't understand what the problem is as I've been granted to the use of that proxy server on IP basis (meaning that only me in the office can use that address).

Any help?

Comment: A HTTP 500 is probably a server side error (at the proxy) rather than an error with your script.  Have you verified with a standard browser that your proxy works as expected?

Comment: Ummm ... yes they should. However, just thinking the proxy authentication method used by these chaps may be a problem. 

What about the other errors reported? Are they normaal?

Comment: Not sure what the other errors mean, I'm not using pydev.  Perhaps you have an incomplete installation.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. I'm a newbie in that term. Just downloaded an IDE and tried to do something. It has asked to use a framework and I've specified the local folder where the 2.7 is on my Mac. I'm even not sure what pydev is and whether there are other version of the framework (or whatever it is called).